# Using Java to login into www.messenger.com

Tags: java, parameter-passing, urlconnection

I am having trouble using code that I found to log into www.messenger.com. It seems like I am not able to write out form parameters because I do not have the right form names. I am having trouble finding the form name of the button and what to set it equal to. My end goal, is to get the html code after I log in.

Source: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/blog/114/entry-2715-login-to-a-website-from-java/

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

private static URL URLObj;
private static URLConnection connect;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        // Establish a URL and open a connection to it. Set it to output mode.
        URLObj = new URL("http://www.messenger.com/#");
        connect = URLObj.openConnection();
        connect.setDoOutput(true);  
    }
    catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
        System.out.println("The URL specified was unable to be parsed or uses an invalid protocol. Please try again.");
        System.exit(1); 
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("An exception occurred. " + ex.getMessage());
        System.exit(1);
    }


    try {
        // Create a buffered writer to the URLConnection's output stream and write our forms parameters.
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(connect.getOutputStream()));
        writer.write("email=MyEmail&pass=MyPassword&submit=Sign In");
        //writer.close();

        // Now establish a buffered reader to read the URLConnection's input stream.
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connect.getInputStream()));

        String lineRead = "";

        // Read all available lines of data from the URL and print them to screen.
        while ((lineRead = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(lineRead);
        }
        reader.close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("There was an error reading or writing to the URL: " + ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: this is just a **fix my code, code dump**

Answer (score 0):

This are the post parameters, that are send by a browser, when you click login:

```
default_persistent=0
email=user
initial_request_id=A2NPA_SLbM3wAkFRM_Y0fLx
lgndim=eyJ3IjoxOTIwLCJoIjoxMjAwLCJhdyI6MTkyMCwiYWgiOjExNjAsImMiOjI0fQ==
lgnjs=n
lgnrnd=125813_Br9w
login=1
lsd=AVrsF9i0
pass=pass
timezone=-120
```

Maybe you need some of these to get a successfull login.

You can find these as hidden parameters in the form with the id "login_form".